# "django-admin" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: python, django, windows-10, django-admin

"django-admin" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Что делать???

Comment: Полагаю, это Windows и питон не прописан в path...

Comment: Я только новичок в этом деле, когда я искал ответ,там было сказано тоже самое, но я не знаю как прописать  этот path и что это вообще такое.

Comment: Я на Windows питон не настраивал ни разу к сожалению, но нашёл схожий вопрос здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7 – попробуйте разобраться в англоязычном решении.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию,но все ровно я хз как это сделать.Может вы знаете.Я пользуюсь pycharm и когда они употребляют слово python я не понимаю что мне делать и как сделать так, что бы с этим взаимодействовал пичарм.P.S У меня винда 10 про

Answer (score 2):

**Либо:**

Кликаем на `мой компьютер` правой кнопкой,потом свойства,потом слева видим список и смотрим на "Дополнительные параметры системы". Кликаем по ней и в открывшемся окошке ищем там кнопку "Параметры среды" и жмём на неё.

Там есть окно `Системные переменные`.
Прокручиваем и ищем строку `Path`.
Кликаем по ней и потом по кнопке `Изменить`.
В поле значение переменной должны быть или нужно будет добавить (чтобы они
были) вот такие строки:

`C:\Python35\Scripts;C:\Python35\`

Как видите ";" это разделитель записей.
Так же ничего от туда не удаляйте и добавьте строки
`C:\Python35\Scripts;C:\Python35\`
в конец записи. Если они уже есть,то ничего добавлять не нужно.
После этого перезагрузите компьютер и потом откройте командную строку
CMD и вбейте в неё python,должен появится питоновский Shell.

**Либо:**
Сделайте как [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk)

**Либо:**

Переустановите Python через экзешник.При установке поставьте галочку на пункте **Add Python to path.**

Comment: Как переустановить пайтон через экзешник?

Comment: >Как переустановить пайтон через экзешник?
Заного установить python

Comment: Тоесть удалить  пайтон , а потом установить?

Comment: Спасибо,целый день ищу ответ на этот вопрос

Comment: У меня ещё есть вопрос(промотайте видеоролик на 1:26 там где он что -то то пишет в path)У меня в path до этого нечего не было написано,случайно не знаете почему?

Comment: УРААААААААА!!! УРА!!! Я БУДУ ДЕЛАТЬ ВЕБСАЙТЫ! УСТАНОВИЛСЯ !!! ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ!!!!!! СПАСИБО!!!!!!!! +REEEEEEEEEEEEP P.S МОЖЕТ НЕ ЗАКРЫВАТЬ ВОПРОС?? МОЖЕТ КОМУ-ТО ПОНАДОБИТЬСЯ

Comment: У меня сейчас новая ошибка, не могу импортировать джанго, и вопрос задать пока не могу =((

Comment: Я скачал и виртуал и всё на свете для джанго

Comment: File "manage.py", line 17, in <module> "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and " ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?