# django не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

После ввода `django-admin` в командую строку появляется такое сообщение:

```
"django-admin" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Совет с ["django-admin" не является внутренней или внешней командой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716530/django-admin-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9) не помог.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Либо у Вас в переменной среды `PATH` нет пути к папке с `django-admin`, либо `django` просто не установлена. Вы же использовали для установки `pip install django`?

Comment: @nomnoms12 да, я использовал `pip install django`

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что `...\Python\Scripts` прописан в переменную среды `Path`? Путь, по которому у Вас установлен `Python`, может отличаться от того, что приведён в вопросе, на который Вы сослались.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я изначально просмотрел свой путь и поставил его

Comment: Может Вы не перезапустили консоль (должны обновиться переменные среды)? Если и это не поможет, то приведите, пожалуйста, в вопрос Вашу запись в `PATH` и путь, по которому у Вас установлен `Python`. Может Вы просто неправильно прописали его?

Comment: @nomnoms12 привел запись в `PATH` и путь по которому установлен `Python`

Comment: `python django-admin`?

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` работает?

Comment: Windows и pip это две несовместимые ужасные вещи, переходите на Linux и жизнь станет проще

Comment: @karaname, вполне совместимые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помимо папки с интерпретатором, Вы также должны добавить папку `Scripts`.
Именно в этой папке находится файл `django-admin`, который не может найти Ваша система.

Добавьте следующую запись в `PATH`:

```
C:\Users\хихи\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

---

Не забудьте после этого перезагрузить консоль, чтобы она подгрузила обновлённую переменную среды.

Comment: все работает, спасибо