# Не работает команда django-admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, веб-программирование, python-3.8

Вроде установил в виртуальное окружение django, по видео уроку написал django-admin startproject mysite и вылетает ошибка "django-admin" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Что делать???

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716530/django-admin-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: http://python.su/forum/topic/26515/